# Proper way to refactor functions that use functions within the same file for testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, redux, jestjs

In our application we need to use different endpoints depending upon whether the current user is authenticated. The status of authentication is stored in Redux state. This is a common pattern I have with redux selectors:

```js
// selectors.js

import {selectIsAuthenticated} from 'Redux/customer/selectors'

export const selectEndpoint = state => selectIsAuthenticated(state) ? 'guest' : 'authenticated'

export const selectEndpointA = state => `/rest/${selectEndpoint(state)}/a`

export const selectEndpointB = state => `/rest/${selectEndpoint(state)}/b`
```

When testing, this becomes complicated because i cannot mock `selectEndpoint`.. so then the test for `selectEndpointA` becomes dependent upon the implementation of `selectEndpoint`, which is not ideal.

What is the proper way to test something like this OR refactor it to be more easily testable?

I have considered refactoring so that selectEndpoint is passed in as an argument (or curried) for `selectEndpointA` such as:

```js
export const selectEndpointA = selectEndpoint => state => `/rest/${selectEndpoint(state)}/a`
```

but this seems overly complicated as now in my code I would need an addition import anywhere that I wanted to use `selectEndpointA`

EDIT:

here's an example of a unit test that I have:

```
import * as selectors from 'Redux/global/selectors'
import * as customerSelectors from 'Redux/customer/selectors'
const nonAuthenticatedEndpoint = 'guest'
/* ... */
  describe('selectEndpoint', () => {
    it('returns proper endpoint for non authenticated user', () => {
      customerSelectors.selectIsAuthenticated = jest.fn(() => false)
      const state = 'state'
      const expected = nonAuthenticatedEndpoint
      expect(selectors.selectEndpoint(state)).toEqual(expected)
      expect(customerSelectors.selectIsAuthenticated).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        state
      )
    })
}
```

so also within `Redux/global/selectors` is `selectEndpointA` and `selectEndpointB`

EDIT:

and an example of a test that i would like to have work:

```
  describe('selectEndpointA', () => {
    it('returns correct endpoint for non authenticated user', () => {
      const state = {
          /* some specific state */
      }
      expect(selectors.selectEndpointA(state)).toEqual('/rest/guest/a')
    })
  })
```

while this does work currently, i would like to find a way to decouple this from the implementation of `selectEndpoint` and have the comparison value not depend upon the return of `selectEndpoint`

Comment: If you are exporting `selectEndpoint` you could stub it in your tests so that it returns what you want. Can you show what you have tried in your test file?

Comment: @mgarcia I do export it for my react components, but i want to test my selectors directly mainly to be able to determine if changes break any functionality

Comment: @mgarcia my understanding is that jest mocks will only work for imports, so because the two functions are in the same file, there is no way for jest to create a mock

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about function mocking, specifically `jest.mock` and [`mockReturnValue`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockreturnvaluevalue). Mock the import and define what your function should return.

```
import * as selectors from 'Redux/global/selectors'
jest.mock('Redux/global/selectors')

selectors.selectEndpointA.mockReturnValue(() => 'whatever you want')
```

Comment: so this destroys all my other tests, for functions under `Redux/global/selectors` that i have in this test file

Comment: I suppose i could remock each function to its true function for the specific test that is testing that function, but that seems to be a step in the wrong direction.. in terms of test verbosity/coupling

Comment: @Paul Split up your selector tests into different separate files. Each file should have its own respective test file. If this _is_ a test file that is tied to a single file, that means that single file is doing too much and should be split up into smaller files

Answer (score 0):

Ok the way I ended up solving this is a combination of currying and default values:

refactored my endpoint selection functions as follows:

```js
// selectors.js

import {selectIsAuthenticated} from 'Redux/customer/selectors'

export const selectEndpoint = state => selectIsAuthenticated(state) ? 'guest' : 'authenticated'

export const selectEndpointA = (endpointSelector = selectEndpoint) => state => `/rest/${endpointSelector(state)}/a`

export const selectEndpointB = (endpointSelector = selectEndpoint) => state => `/rest/${endpointSelector(state)}/b`
```

and the resulting tests...

```js
  describe('selectEndpointA', () => {
    it('returns correct endpoint', () => {
      const test = 'test'
      const state = 'state'
      const selectEndpoint = jest.fn(() => test)
      expect(selectors.selectEndpointA(selectEndpoint)(state)).toEqual(`/rest/${test}/a`)
      expect(selectEndpoint).toHaveBeenCalledWith(state)
    })
  })
```

and then because there is a default value, it means that in my usage elsewhere I can use:

```
const endpointA = selectEndpointA()(state)
```

and not be concerned with what function is deciding how the endpoint is determined, nor exactly what that function returns (but can test that separately)